# org-capture buffer not showing schedule/deadline/time

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

If I use `org-capture` via `C-c c t`, I type in my headline (eg. "a new task") and press `Enter`, it takes me to a capture buffer, as expected. I can change the priority of the item there (eg. Shift-UP). However, if I try to add a schedule/deadline via `C-c C-s/d`, I get a calendar showing up nicely, and I can choose a date, but it doesn't show in the buffer itself. If I complete the capture via `C-c C-c`, the item itself in the org file has the scheduled date I chose, even though it wasn't visible in the capture buffer.

I'd like to be able to see the scheduled date in the capture buffer, so I can add time info to it (eg. 11:00) before refiling. Otherwise, I have to go locate it, and add that info.

This *used* to work for me, so I guess it's some package update thing... does anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**
Emacs version: 27.1
org version: 9.3

capture template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
        `(("t" "Task" entry (file+headline "~/org/work.org" "Unfiled Tasks") "* TODO %^{Task}\n")
          ("n" "Note" entry (file "") "* %^{Note}\n" :immediate-finish t)
          ("i" "Interrupting task" entry (file+headline "~/org/todo.org" "Unfiled Tasks") "* STARTED %^{Task}" :clock-in :clock-resume)
      ("a" "Anniversary" entry (file+headline "~/org/calendar.org" "Birthdays/Anniversaries") "* %^{Anniversary}\nSCHEDULED" :imediate-finish t)
          ("j" "Journal entry with date" plain (file+datetree+prompt "~/org/journal.org") "%K - %a\n%i\n%?\n" :unnarrowed t)))
```

(NOTE: I notice this on the "t").

Comment: What version of Org mode and Emacs are you using?

Comment: Let's see your capture template.

Comment: Sorry, should have put that info in the question. It's in there now.

Comment: This has fixed itself somehow.